# How to do a close window button within a div?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to do a close window button within a div. How to make it work in Javascript?

**HTML**

```
<div class="row justify-content-center" id="closeBox"></div>
          <button onclick="???">Close Window</button>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
    //What goes here?
</script>
```

Comment: Which window you want to close?

Comment: The current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `window.close`:

```
<button onclick="window.close()">Close Window</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Call some **js** function on button click like

```
<div class="row justify-content-center" id="closeBox"></div>
          <button onclick="closeWindow()">Close Window</button>
</div>
```

then in script add the function as

```
var closeWindow = function(){
   window.close()
}
```

Rather if you want to close or hide the parante div(**#closeBox**), change the function as

```
var closeWindow = function(){
       document.getElementById("closeBox").style.display = 'none';
}
```